# The use of へ towards an abstract concept

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-へ

I understand the obvious uses of へ. My understanding gets a bit fuzzy when it comes to things other than a physical direction toward a physical place.

For example; a sentence such as this: 勝ちへ向かう

Is this limited to just goals/expectations? Is there any limit to what goals/expectations can use this particle? Honestly, I wish this particle could just mean 'to' in general. :/

Comment: I can't help but notice a slight irony in how in your question title you used "towards" in English in reference to an abstract concept ;)

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing special about 勝ち in the sentence. In fact, I think you can safely think of へ as "to, toward, towards", both for physical and metaphorical direction.

> 日本語の理解へ !
> Towards a better understanding of Japanese!
>
> 明るい未来へ !
> Towards a brighter future!

Answer (score 1):

The use of "へ" does not depend much on the relationship.
For "向かう", however, there are two meanings.

A:

> "駅へ向かう"

I headed to the station.

```
I headed to *the destination*.
```

B:

> "勝ちへ向かう"

I headed for the win.

```
I headed for *the state(or the time)*.
```